# Error while integrating stripe payment in laravel 9

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-9

I am integrating stripe payment gateway in laravel 9. While integrating I am getting error on the form submit. I am getting error on the following line

```
stripe.createToken(cardElement).then(function (result) {
```

I have attached my js file and error screenshot

```
   var clientSecret = null;
    var elements = null;
    
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    const stripe = Stripe(form.getAttribute('data-stripe-publishable-key'));
    const completeUrl = form.getAttribute('data-complete-url');
    $('#stripe-loading').show();
    
    if (clientSecret == null) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/initiate-payment',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData($('#payment-form')[0]),
            datatype: "json",
            async: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                clientSecret = response.client_secret;
            }
        });
    }
    
    const options = {
        clientSecret,
        appearance: {
            theme: 'stripe',
            variables: {
                colorPrimary: '#0570de',
                colorBackground: '#ffffff',
                colorText: '#30313d',
                colorTextSecondary: '#dadbe0',
                colorDanger: '#df1b41',
                fontFamily: 'Ideal Sans, system-ui, sans-serif',
                spacingUnit: '2px',
                borderRadius: '4px',
            },
            rules: {
                '.Input': {
                    'padding': '8px 20px',
                    'borderRadius': '18px',
                    'marginBottom': '8px',
                    'color': '#5B657E',
                    'border': '1px solid transparent',
                },
                '.Error': {
                    'color': '#ffffff',
                }
            },
            labels: 'floating',
        },
    };
    
    elements = stripe.elements(options);
    var cardElement = elements.create('payment');
    cardElement.mount('#card-element');
    cardElement.on('ready', () => {
        $('#stripe-loading').hide()
    });
    
    cardElement.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        if (event.error) {
            displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
            displayError.textContent = '';
        }
    });
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        stripe.createToken(cardElement).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result.error) {
                var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
                stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            }
        });
    });
```

[image]

This is the first time I am integrating payment gateway. Hoping someone can help me

Comment: You should add `.catch` block to your `stripe.createToken` Promise chain to log the actual error thrown. It's currently uncaught as per the error you're seeing.

Comment: @JonathanSteele I enclosed stripe.createToken in a try-catch block. And only curly braces are showing as error